Why were humans in possession of the three dangerous artifacts in YuYu Hakusho's live-action adaptation?
I've been watching Yu Yu Hakusho, the 2023 Netflix live-action adaptation of the 1990 manga. I've noticed some confusing plot points, particularly regarding three dangerous artifacts: the Rapacious Orb, the Mirror of Darkness, and the Conjuring Blade.
In episode 2, Koenma mentions that "three dangerous objects that were being monitored by the Spirit World were stolen by three yokai thieves." He was referring to the scene at the end of episode 1, where human SWAT-type units or mercenaries were fighting what I can only describe as "zombie yokai" (the English subtitles just call them "things"). Botan and Koenma comment that Yusuke wouldn't stand a chance against these creatures at that point.

The zombie yokai defeat the humans and take the three artifacts, but they're then beaten by Goki, Kurama, and Hiei (the "three yokai thieves"), who make off with the objects.
Koenma describes these artifacts as "dangerous objects with huge powers" and warns that if they aren't recovered quickly, "the Human World will be in trouble!" This implies that the artifacts aren't from the Human World, but rather from the Spirit World or the Demon (Yokai) World.
Who were those humans initially in possession of these non-Human World artifacts? And how did they get their hands on them in the first place? Did they somehow take them from the Spirit or Demon World? If so, how did they manage that? From what I understand, a human would have to be dead to access the Spirit World, and there's a barrier preventing access to the Demon World. (In episode 3, Younger Toguro mentions that he's assisting Sakyo in his project so he can go to the Demon World.)
I realize that this live-action adaptation is quite condensed, squeezing several volumes of the manga into just five episodes. Because of this, I suspect some plot explanations might have been lost in the process.

What's with the downvote? Is there something obvious I missed?

(I haven't seen the live action series, I only watched the animated one ages ago and I never read the manga, so this is mainly speculation) Maybe the three artefacts have been in the human world for years / centuries (lost/gifted by inhabitants of the Spirit World?), with time becoming important cultural / religiouos objects held in museums / secure vaults that the Underworld rulers cannot just spirit away. Note that the sword + mirror + jewel combination matches with the Imperial Regalia of Japan.
